# Antipodal in the 2-torus

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm strugling to understandind the antipodal in the 2-torus. In this thread

[Embedding of Klein bottle in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and Klein bottle as quotient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972750/embedding-of-klein-bottle-in-mathbbr4-and-klein-bottle-as-quotient?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I find " the antipodal mapping $A:S\to S$ can be expressed as $(x, y)\mapsto(x+1/2,-y)$". But I don't understand since if I put for instance $x=0.7$ then  $x+\frac{1}{2}\notin [0,1]$ in the same way $-y \notin[0,1]$ for any $y \in [0,1]$, but the parametrization of torus is defined in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ according the thread above, So i don't know how fix this information.

Other doubt is: Why the autor of thread increasing the angle $4\pi$ in the function $G$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much do you understand the [universal property of quotient maps,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493993/universal-property-in-quotient-topology) as it is taught in a topology course?

Comment: $S=\Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$ hence $A$ is to be understood $\bmod1.$